# python serial to arduino speed test

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial, loopback

i'm trying to make a serial speed test between my computer and the Arduino with python (pyserial 3.0.1). I connected the Arduino Duemilanove (ATmega328) via USB with my Ubuntu VM. The device shows up perfectly and i flashed it with this simple loopback sketch via the arduino IDE (1.6.7):

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  while(Serial.available()) {
    Serial.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

My python program looks like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudrate=115200,
    timeout=1
)

i = 0;

#wait until bootloader finished
time.sleep(2)

try:
    t0 = time.time()
    while i < 1000:
        ser.write(b'U')
        ser.flush()
        while ser.in_waiting <= 0:
            pass
        ret = ser.read(1)
        if ret != 'U':
            print("Error received: %s" % ret)
        i += 1
    t1 = time.time()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    ser.close()
    exit(1)

ser.close()

print("%.3f" % (t1-t0))
```

The Problem is, it work sometimes and sometimes the python program does not return and i have to Ctrl-C out of it. If this happens i can't see the arduino RX and TX leds blinking.

Does someone know why this happens?

Thank you very much... draufundrann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I switched over to my "real" (not VM) Linux machine and it seems to work just fine over there. I will do some more testing and eventually i will close this question.

EDIT: So I confirmed it's sometimes works in the Ubuntu VM and it always works with my real Linux Mint machine. Since i don't need to use the VM and i don't care why its not realy working (probably some weard VM stuff) i will close this question.